# How to get x-axis value in wx canvas from mouse click?

Tags: python, graph, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wx plot which is defined like so

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas
import pylab


class GraphFrame(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, chart_name, nsamples, varnames, krefresh=150):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    self.display_function = self._display_abs

    self.need_to_copy_background = False

    self.chart_name = chart_name
    self.nsamples = nsamples
    self.varnames = varnames
    self.krefresh = krefresh

    self.data = np.zeros((self.nsamples, len(self.varnames)))

    self._create_panel(chart_name)

def _create_panel(self, chart_name=None):
    self.init_plot()

    self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)

    self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.vbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

    self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
    self.vbox.Fit(self)

def set_title(self, new_title):
    self.axes.set_title(new_title, size=10)
    self.canvas.draw()

def init_plot(self):
    self.yrange = [-1.0, +1.0]
    self.yrange2 = [-555.0, +555.0]
    t0 = -0.125
    t1 = 0.0
    self.time = np.linspace(t0, t1, self.nsamples)
    self.k = 0
    self.dpi = 100
    self.fig = Figure(dpi=self.dpi)
    self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)
    self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.axes2 = self.axes.twinx()
    self.axes.set_title(self.chart_name, size=10)
    self.axes.grid(True)

    pylab.setp(self.axes.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=8)
    pylab.setp(self.axes.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)
    pylab.setp(self.axes2.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)
    self.plot = []
    self.plot2 = []

    for i in range(len(self.varnames)):
        ax = self.axes.plot([],
                            [],
                            "%s-" % ("krgbym"[i]),
                            linewidth=0.5,
                            color=(0, 0, 1))[0]
        ax2 = self.axes2.plot(
                            [],
                            [],
                            "%s-" % ("krgbym"[i]),
                            linewidth=2,
                            color=(1, 0, 0)
                            )[0]

        self.plot.append(ax)
        self.plot2.append(ax2)

def draw_plot(self):
    data = self.data[:, 0]
    occ = self.data[:, 1]
    self.need_to_copy_background = True
    dmin = data.min()
    dmax = data.max()
    if dmin == 0.0 and dmax == 0.0:
        self.yrange = [-1.0, +1.0]
        self.need_to_copy_background= False
    elif dmin < self.yrange[0] or dmax > self.yrange[1]:
        self.yrange[0] = dmin - 0.1666 * (dmax - dmin)
        self.yrange[1] = dmax + 0.1666 * (dmax - dmin)
        self.need_to_copy_background= False
    elif (dmax - dmin) < 0.25 * (self.yrange[1] - self.yrange[0]):
        self.yrange[0] = dmin - 0.1666 * (dmax - dmin)
        self.yrange[1] = dmax + 0.1666 * (dmax - dmin)
        self.need_to_copy_background= False
    ymin = self.yrange[0]
    ymax = self.yrange[1]

    self.need_to_copy_background = False

    self.axes.set_xbound(0, self.nsamples)
    self.axes.set_ybound(lower=ymin, upper=ymax)

    self.axes2.set_ybound(lower=occ.min(), upper=occ.max())

    t0 = -0.125
    t1 = 0.0
    self.time = np.linspace(t0, t1, self.nsamples)

    self.plot[0].set_data(np.arange(self.nsamples), data)

    self.plot2[0].set_data(np.arange(self.nsamples), occ)

    if self.need_to_copy_background:
        self.copy_background()
        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        for i in range(len(self.varnames)):
            self.axes.draw_artist(self.plot[i])
            self.axes2.draw_artist(self.plot2[i])
        self.canvas.blit(self.fig.bbox)
    else:
        self.canvas.draw()

def copy_background(self):
    self.axes.cla()
    self.axes.set_xlim(self.time[0], self.time[-1])
    self.axes.set_ylim(self.yrange[0], self.yrange[1])
    for i in range(len(self.varnames)):
        self.plot[i] = self.axes.plot([], [], "%s-" % ("krgby"[i]), lw=2.0)[0]
    self.axes.grid(True)

    self.axes2.cla()
    self.axes2.set_xlim(self.time[0], self.time[-1])
    self.axes2.set_ylim(self.yrange2[0], self.yrange2[1])
    for i in range(len(self.varnames)):
        self.plot2[i] = self.axes2.plot([], [], "%s-" % ("krgby"[i]), lw=2.0)[0]
    self.axes2.grid(True)

    self.canvas.draw()
    self.background = self.canvas.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.canvas.figure.bbox)

def _display_abs(self, v):
    return np.abs(v)

def add_data(self, val):
    self.data[:-1] = self.data[1:]
    self.data[-1] = self.display_function(val)
    self.k += 1

    if (self.k % self.krefresh) == 0:
        self.draw_plot()
```

This works fine.

When add_data is called, the graph is updated and refreshed correctly.

---

I want to add a feature that would allow the user to mouse click on somewhere on the graph (canvas), and a callback would be issued with an argument that has the x-value of the selected point on the graph.

For example

```
Y  
^  
|    /\  /\
|   /  \/  \  X<<< pressing on this point would give 14
|  /        \  _
| /          \/ \_
|/_________________________>x  
012345678901234567890123456
```

Pressing the point where the X is on the beautiful graph above should return 14, as the X value at that point is 14.

Notice, if the X value does not start from 0, is float (and not int), or anything, else, still the data's value should be returned, and not the data's index.

---

Is this possible with wx? How?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is built into mpl, see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html

> cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

I created this sample to try it out and it works perfectly.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import _load_bitmap
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np

import wx

class MyNavigationToolbar(NavigationToolbar):
    """Extend the default wx toolbar with your own event handlers."""

    def __init__(self, canvas, cankill):
        NavigationToolbar.__init__(self, canvas)

        # for simplicity I'm going to reuse a bitmap from wx, you'll
        # probably want to add your own.
        tool = self.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Click me', _load_bitmap('back.png'),
                            'Activate custom contol')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self._on_custom, id=tool.GetId())

    def _on_custom(self, evt):
        # add some text to the axes in a random location in axes (0,1)
        # coords) with a random color

        # get the axes
        ax = self.canvas.figure.axes[0]

        # generate a random location can color
        x, y = np.random.rand(2)
        rgb = np.random.rand(3)

        # add the text and draw
        ax.text(x, y, 'You clicked me',
                transform=ax.transAxes,
                color=rgb)
        self.canvas.draw()
        evt.Skip()


class CanvasFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,
                          'CanvasFrame', size=(550, 350))

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

        self.axes.plot(t, s)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)

        self.toolbar = MyNavigationToolbar(self.canvas, True)
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        # By adding toolbar in sizer, we are able to put it at the bottom
        # of the frame - so appearance is closer to GTK version.
        self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)

        # update the axes menu on the toolbar
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.OnClick)

        #self.canvas.Bind(wx.MOUSE_BTN_LEFT, self.OnClick)

    def OnClick(self, e):
        print('%s click: button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          ('double' if e.dblclick else 'single', e.button,
           e.x, e.y, e.xdata, e.ydata))


class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
        frame = CanvasFrame()
        frame.Show(True)

        return True

app = App(0)
app.MainLoop()
```